# jQuery select multiple table columns by index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen certain questions knocking around which are similar, but not exactly the same and I'm stumped with this one.

What I'm trying to do is create a widget that takes a table, then goes through the table's td elements and sets a cursor:pointer (for now) to them, but only the ones that I allow.

This is how my code looks:

```
selectableGrid: function (options) {
            var indexes = options.columns // this is [1,2];

            return this.each(function () {
                // Make the td's in the grid selectable
                $(this).find("tbody td").attr("style", "cursor:pointer");
            });
        }
```

The end result I'm wanting to achieve?

```
<tbody>
   <td>hello</td> // index 0
   <td style="cursor:pointer">hello</td> //index 1
   <td style="cursor:pointer">hello</td> // index 2
</tbody>
```

Bear in mind that I could be sending through 1,3 in my array list of columns, so lt and gt don't work for my scenario (as far as I've tried anyway).

EDIT:
In order to achieve this I went with the following code:

```
$(this).find("tr").each(function () {
         $(this).find("td").each(function (i, el) {
                if (indexes.indexOf(i) > -1) {
                    $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
                };
         });
});
```

For some reason "tbody td" wouldn't work for a singular loop as it only referenced the first iteration of the  tag.

Thank you once again Stack Overflow.

Comment: Instead of `.attr("style", "cursor:pointer");` you should use `.css("cursor", "pointer");` -- using `.attr` will overwrite any existing inline styles.

Comment: Thank you for that little tip - changed my code to use that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.each` takes an `index` parameter you can reference in your code.....:

```
var indexes = options.columns;
this.find("tbody td").each(function(i, el) {
    if ($.inArray(i,indexes)>-1) { // good idea, ggreiner
        $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
    };
});
```

Comment: but this will only work if there is one row in the table. And I believe the order of the parameters for [`inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) is backwards

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the `td` elements, and check that their index with respect to their siblings is an index contained in the `options.columns` array.

```
selectableGrid: function (options) {
    var indexes = options.columns // this is [1,2];
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).find("tbody td").each(function(){
            var columnIndex = $(this).index();
            if($.inArray(columnIndex, options.columns) != -1){
               $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

loop through your indexes and use the http://api.jquery.com/eq/ to find the particular td.

Comment: I tried this approach and couldn't get it working with: $(this).find("tbody td").eq(value).css("style", "cursor:pointer"); where value = the index (1,2).